# Android - JSONObject doesn't work

Tags: android, http-get, json

I'm using `HttpGet` method in my `REST API` on Android and I have a problem. I get the response but I can't create the object that it's being retrieved. Here I put my `AsyncTask`:

```
class FindCar extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Void> {

   protected void onPreExecute(){
   }

   protected Void doInBackground(Integer... idCar) {

      String name = ""; 

      String url = "http://IP of my computer/project/cars/" + idCar[0].intValue();

      HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

      HttpGet method = new HttpGet(url);

      method.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");

      try {
          HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(method);

          String respStr = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());

          Log.d("prove", respStr); //Here I get {"name":"Car1"}

          JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(respStr);

          name = obj.getString("name");

          Log.d("prove", name); //Nothing appears

      } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

          return null;
   }

   protected void onProgressUpdate(){
   }

   protected void onPostExecute(){
   }
}
```

Why, if my response it's being retrieved, the object isn't created?
Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT:** I make a lot of proves and in my real code I have `respStr` but I copy the prove that I make before. Sorry.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please can someone explain me why the downvote is?

Comment: it was not me who downvote but I imagine is because your question is "why this doesn't work". Did you try put `Log.d("prove", ex.getMEssage);` inside the `catch(Exception ex)` ? It's probably crashing someone but if you don't check it, you'll never know.

Comment: considering the `respStr` shows and the `name` doesn't I would guess it's a malformed JSON string.

Comment: @Budius I know that I put why it doesn't work but I put my example with what I have tried, it's why I didn't understand it. And in the catch the Log it's not displayed so I suppose that it is not going there.

Comment: so what are the next steps if you even learnt how to debug anything? Put a breakpoint and go line by line.

Comment: @Budius Ok the object it's created. The problem it's when I use `obj.getString("name");` that it's not retrieving nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

Finally I got the solution. What I did?

Remove this sentence:

```
name = obj.getString("name");
```

and rewrite it again (put exactly the same as before).

And works! Just incredible...

Please if someone knows what happens here let me know. I'm really intrigued about this.

Answer (score 0):

What is i??

Instead of doing this:

```
JSONObject obj = respJSON.getJSONObject(i);
```

Do this:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(respStr);
```

Comment: Oh sorry in my real code I have `respStr` instead of `i`. Just a mistake copying it here. Sorry. Now edited as I have and it also doesn't work.

Comment: Still doesn't work. It was what I had in my real code (sorry again for my mistake).

Comment: have you even tried changing  your code from getJSONObject to new JSONObject as mentioned in my answer

Comment: check by printing your respStr, that whether you are receiving required response or not

Comment: My `respStr` gives to me `{"name":"Car1"}` as I put in the comments of the code

Answer (score 0):

You got response in `respStr` but you do not seem to use it anywhere, you got `respJSON` which is who-knows-what and you use it for unknown reason and not to mention you use `i` which comes out of nowhere. You should create your response JSON just like that:

```
      String respStr = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());
      JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(respStr);
```

Comment: Yes, sorry. I had a mistake copying my real code here. But still doesn't work.

Comment: what doesn't work means really? you need to change your code as mentioned above.

Comment: That, when I try to get `name` nothing it's stored in the variable but the response, as you can see, it's being retrieved.

Comment: because you create `obj` wrong. you need to do as I wrote

Comment: Can you post what your response look like in json string? It might be you getting wrong tag or format?